# Fault tolerant yarn-client mode with Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Are there any facilities to come back from failure in the scenario that a running client application opens a driver program to yarn in the client mode and its spark context dies?

I know that cluster mode allows for this--but my application runs programatically with an existing context and not through spark submit.

Comment: what do you mean by *come back from failure scenario*?  Do you want to do some processing after a failure? or You just want to stop your application  gracefully?